# Get number of rows returned by subquery along with the columns returned by subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I find it really annoying to be not able to get the number of rows without having to use group by. I just need to get the "Total count" that my subquery returned.

Here is what my subquery looks like:

```
select sales_flat_order.increment_id, sales_flat_order.created_at, sales_flat_order.status, dispatch.dispatch_date, 
DATEDIFF(TO_DATE(dispatch.dispatch_date), TO_DATE(sales_flat_order.created_at)) as delay 
FROM 
magentodb.sales_flat_order 
LEFT OUTER JOIN erpdb.dispatch 
ON 
sales_flat_order.increment_id == dispatch.order_num 
where
TO_DATE(created_at) >= DATE_SUB(current_date(),6)
AND 
TO_DATE(created_at) <= DATE_SUB(current_date(), 3)
AND
sales_flat_order.status NOT IN ('canceled', 'exchange', 'rto', 'pending_auth', 'pending_payment' ,'partial_refund','refund', 'refund_cash', 'partial_refund_cash', 'holded')
)
AS TempFiltered
```

Now, I add 1 extra `WHERE` clause in my outer query so that it returned "lesser" number of rows, let's call this `column y` .

I then  require to take percentage of x to y(i.e number of rows returned by outer query to subquery)

I do not wan to repeat my subquery only to get count of the rows. HOw do I get it?

This is what I have so far: But ofcourse it is wrong. I can not get count of all my rows without having to exclude select columns or using them in group by. HOw do I resolve this?

```
SELECT tempfiltered.delay, count(*) as countOfOrders,(100*count(*))/tempfiltered.Total) over () as percentage
FROM
(
select count(*) as Total, sales_flat_order.increment_id, sales_flat_order.created_at, sales_flat_order.status, dispatch.dispatch_date, 
DATEDIFF(TO_DATE(dispatch.dispatch_date), TO_DATE(sales_flat_order.created_at)) as delay 
FROM 
magentodb.sales_flat_order 
LEFT OUTER JOIN erpdb.dispatch 
ON 
sales_flat_order.increment_id == dispatch.order_num 
where
TO_DATE(created_at) >= DATE_SUB(current_date(),6)
AND 
TO_DATE(created_at) <= DATE_SUB(current_date(), 3)
AND
sales_flat_order.status NOT IN ('canceled', 'exchange', 'rto', 'pending_auth', 'pending_payment' ,'partial_refund','refund', 'refund_cash', 'partial_refund_cash', 'holded')
)
AS TempFiltered
Where 
 DATEDIFF(TO_DATE(TempFiltered.dispatch_date), TO_DATE(TempFiltered.created_at)) > 1     
GROUP BY tempfiltered.delay
ORDER BY tempfiltered.delay
```

Comment: This `TO_DATE` is an oracle function, no? Your previous question was for `hive`. I am not sure you know how to tag things.

Comment: I actually do but since most of the hive questions go unanswered and hive is more like sql only, tagged it in sql. But yeah , I get it, should have at least mentioned so in the note.  @Drew

Comment: So your platform is hadoop and hive? Oracle, who knows. The reason they go unanswered is cuz no one uses the foobar thing. And like your previous question people were confused. And I was about to give you a mysql cross join that wouldn't even work on your system. You are wasting your time and others. Tag stuff the right way.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the subquery into a SELECT INTO query, and put the data in a temporary table, and use that in the main query, and separately just select count(*) of that temporary table. That should pretty much satisfy your requirement.

Comment: To involve a temp table is usually the worst approach to everything